# Is there a comparison of Ethereum smart contracts to other platforms that also have smart contracts?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

Doing some research in the smart contracts arena. But is there an in depth comparisons with the pros/cons of each implementation of smart contracts in other blockchains as compared to Ethereum smart contracts? What are the strength and weaknesses of each?

Comment: Relevant: multi-part series, starting here: https://medium.com/on-the-origin-of-smart-contract-platforms/on-the-origin-of-smart-contract-platforms-ff466b7bb839